# Deck of cards error java

Tags: java

```
public class Cards {
private Cards deck[];
private int currentcard;
private static final int Number_of_Cards=52;
private static final Random randomNumbers= new Random();
public DeckofCards()
{
    String[] faces = {"Ace", "Deuce", "Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King"};
    String[] suits ={"Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs","Spades"};
    deck = new Cards[Number_of_Cards];
    currentcard=0;
    for (int c=0; c<deck.length; c++)
        deck[c]= new Cards(faces[c%13],suits[c/13]); //error here
   }
  }
```

This is the code i have so far in order to fill my Deck of cards, this is from a java learning book though it seems i have an error in that last line:
`Constructor Cards in class Cards cannot be applied to given types: required:no arguments found:String,String reason:actual and formal argument lists differ in length`

Thanks for help!

Comment: have you implemented the consturctor Cards(String, String)?

Comment: this is exactly my whole code, so i guess not, can you please explain how to do that? i am completely new in Java

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a object `new Cards(faces[c%13],suits[c/13]);` with parameters, but your `Cards` class doesn't have a constructor which takes arguments. Create a constructor which takes two `String` arguments.

Comment: okay if but then why does the learning book (Java by Deitel)from which i found the code has it exactly like this?

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified any constructor (so obviously a constructor that has two String arguments does not exists) and therefor only a default constructor is assumed by Java

Comment: can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: You need to have constructor like public Cards(String face, String suit) {//doSomething}

Comment: Can you point me to the source code of the examples you are using?

Comment: do you mean to tell you the page of the book i am getting this code from?

Comment: The book has it's source code on the web doesn't it? What version of the book do you have, which chapter are you on and which example is it in the chapter?

Comment: I have the real book, i am not looking it through the web. The book is java by paul and harvey deitel 8th edition i am on chapter 7, on example 7.10, page 262(though it might not be exactly the same page cause it is translated to my language)

Comment: never mind i found my own error, i missed a page of the example where he created the Class Cards, when i was on the page i did the mistake i assumed the class Cards existed in default by java...